# How do you call the ruby-git push command with <repository> and <refspec> options?

Tags: ruby, git, ssh, ruby-git

This is the library I'm referring to: https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git

I am trying to translate the following command into this library's Git module

`git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/repo push --no-verify ssh://git.my.url/pkg/repo-name <commit_hash>:refs/heads/head`

This is what I have so far:

```rb
  git = Git.clone(some_ssh_url)
  ... git add and git commit commands
  git.push(
    remote: "#{some_ssh_url}",
    branch: "#{git.revparse('HEAD~0').strip}:refs/heads/head",
    opts: { '--no-verify' => '' }
  )
```

This produces the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    6: from /***:in `<main>'
    5: from /***:in `main'
    4: from /***:in `method_a'
    3: from /***:in `method_b'
    2: from /***:in `push'
    1: from /***/RubyGem-git/RubyGem-git-1.5.x.1579.0/AL2_x86_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/ruby2.7.x/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/git-1.5.0/lib/git/lib.rb:767:in `push'
/***/RubyGem-git/RubyGem-git-1.5.x.1579.0/AL2_x86_64/DEV.STD.PTHREAD/build/ruby2.7.x/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/git-1.5.0/lib/git/lib.rb:967:in `command': git '--git-dir=/***/.git' '--work-tree=/***' push '{:opts=>{"--no-verify"=>"", "ssh://git.my.url/pkg/***"=>"", "<commit_hash>:refs/heads/head"=>""}}' 'master'  2>&1:error: src refspec master does not match any (Git::GitExecuteError)
error: failed to push some refs to '{:opts=>{"--no-verify"=>"", "ssh://git.my.url/pkg/***"=>"", "<commit_hash>:refs/heads/head"=>""}}'
```

It's not clear whether I've translated the command correctly but when I run `git --git-dir=/path/to/repo/.git --work-tree=/path/to/repo push --no-verify ssh://git.my.url/pkg/repo-name <commit_hash>:refs/heads/head` with `Open3` it goes through, so my guess is that what I have in ruby-git is not equivalent.

Has anyone used ruby-git, and knows how to do something similar like is described [here](https://howto.lintel.in/git-how-to-push-code-to-repository-on-remote-ssh-server/)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't https://github.com/ruby-git/ruby-git/blob/45aeac931b346cc73666ac03521ebfb0cd52fd93/lib/git/lib.rb#L886-L902

Send a pull request to extend the library. It's open source :)